# PUSH notifications ain't working in distribution

Tags: ios, push-notification

I was testing push notifications on developer certificate and everything worked fine. After switching to distribution certificate and publishing the app notifications are not working.

Tokens are generated because my database is filled with them, but still notifications are not recieved.

**Is there a way I could test out distribution build** (signed with distrubution certificate)? I've build the app for ad hoc development signed with distribution certificate but I can't install it on any device, neither by iTunes (process is stuck on installing after clicking reyed out icon on device) or iFunBox.

I've checked the code signing and development was signed with develompment profile, and distribution with distrubution profile. **But there also was provisining profile selected. I've readen that there should be selected "none". Could that be the reason?**

I can't afford waiting another 6 days for approval not being sure that this time it works perfectly.

Comment: if you getting tokens your device seems to work. Do you use the right certificates on your push-server? Are you using the right gateway?

Comment: As @JonathanCichon mentioned, the gateways is different between sandbox and production. So you need to use that as your gateway. Furthermore make sure you install on your device an Ad-Hoc or Release build, as Debug builds have a different Push Device Token, so you won't be getting the pushes if your phone as a debug build

Comment: I'm trying to install the app ad hoc signed with distrubution certificate but the icon is greyed out and instalation is stuck on Installing...

Comment: @Xylian you can not use the same certificate for distribution and ad-hoc. You need a specific certificate for ad-hoc.

Comment: ANd what if I use options + run and change it to release on xcode? Will that do?

Comment: no, you will have to create an explicit adhoc-distribution profile and sign the app with this. You can not build+run the app with this, you have to archive etc. it and install it with the organizer or itunes. But this will only work with an adhoc profile not with an distribution profile.

Comment: Will adhoc generate same tokens as distribution would?

Comment: yes this should work with the same gateways as distribution.

Comment: well I did that, app got installed but it fails to aquire token. DO I have to create another app id for that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39494/discussion-between-jonathan-cichon-and-xylian)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing distribution build I just deployed it for AdHoc deployment. It helped me to veryfi if it works on distribution;

Answer (score 1):

When you run PUSH notification with distribution certificate you have to set **sandbox=false** at your server side .